# How does one write a plugin for a language in Eclipse?

Tags: .net, eclipse, build, eclipse-plugin, mono

I want to write a plugin for .NET/Mono C# Development in Eclipse. Current plugins such as Emonic only provide support for .NET/Mono up to 3.5, and aren't very well documented and/or out of date.

Emonic uses a build tool called NAnt, which is maintained and works for .NET/Mono 4.0. I suppose this is how I will implement building of my projects.

I'm wondering how to do this using Idiomatic Eclipse Plugin development. Any guides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO although learning how to write an Eclipse language binding may be a very interesting experience, you will always be better off trying to get involved in Emonic development and fix it for your needs. Even if it is painful the first weeks, you'll clearly not regret it when you start realising all the time that you saved by not starting from scratch.

PS: A software component doesn't need to be "very well documented" to be understandable. Just dig into the code. Otherwise the new plugin you write today will be the "not very well documented" code for a developer tomorrow, and we will never progress.

Answer (score 3):

Adding support for a new programming language in Eclipse can be rather easy and hellish difficult depending on your ambitions.

For the initial work on an editor that is capable of syntax highlighting and some limited content assist, have a look at [XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/). You "just" need a BNF grammar to get started.

If you want to go further than that - e.g. with support for type assist and building - you better have a close look at JDT (the Java Development Tools of Eclipse) and likely buy one or more of the books on the subject (I can recommend "[Eclipse Plugins, 3rd Edition](http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=441)" but there are [quite a few available](http://www.eclipse.org/resources/?type=book)).